# How to access the request.user in a Piston classmethod

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I have a model which contains a ManyToMany to User to keep track of which users have 'favorited' a particular model instance.

In my API for this model, when requested by an authenticated user, I'd like to include an 'is_favorite' boolean. However, it seems that any api fields that aren't straight model attributes must be implemented as a class method, which when called in Piston does not get a reference to the request object, and therefore I have no way to know who the current user is.

From the Piston docs:

*In addition to these, you may define any other methods you want. You can use these by including their names in the fields directive, and by doing so, **the function will be called with a single argument: The instance of the model.** It can then return anything, and the return value will be used as the value for that key.*

So, if only the Piston CRUD methods get an instance of the request, how can my classmethod fields generate output which is relevant to the current authenticated user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of the piston API, but how about using the thread locals middleware to access the request

add this to middleware

```
try:                                                                    
    from threading import local                                         
except ImportError:                                                     
    from django.utils._threading_local import local                     

_thread_locals = local()                                                
def get_request():                                                
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'request', None)                       

class ThreadLocals(object):                                             
    def process_request(self, request):                                 
        _thread_locals.request = request
```

and update the settings with the ThreadLocals middleware

and wherever you want to access the request `import get_request` from middleware

if you want to just get the current user, modify the middleware to set only `request.user` in thread locals

Comment: Nice workaround to what appears to be a deficiency in the Piston API. I think the real 'right' answer should be something completely different, but this did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the piston [wiki page](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) it says that you may specify the contents of foreign keys and many to many fields by nesting attributes. In your case

```
class FriendHandler(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)
    model = User
    fields = ('userfield_1', 'userfield_2', ('friends', ('is_friended')))

    def read(self, request):
        # Anything else you might want to do, but return an object of type User
        # Or whatever your model happens to be called
```

**EDIT:** Another slightly hacky way to do it (if you don't want the friend to get passed at all if the is_friended is false) would be to manually create a dict object structured how you like, and then return it. piston processes the dict a works with the built in emitters (the JSON one for sure, haven't tried the others)