# How to access the request.user in a Django Piston @classmethod?

Tags: django, django-piston

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the request.user in a Piston classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580653/how-to-access-the-request-user-in-a-piston-classmethod)

How to access the request.user in a Django Piston @classmethod?

In the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation) about the classmethod it's reported:

> ...In addition to these, you may define any other methods you want.
>   You can use these by including their names in the fields directive,
>   and by doing so, the function will be called with a single argument:
>   The instance of the model.

Answer (score 1):

The request object in piston is passed to the corresponding [resource](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!resources) methods

> **read** is called on GET requests, and should never modify data
>   (idempotent.)
>
> **create** is called on POST, and creates new objects, and should return
>   them (or rc.CREATED.)
>
> **update** is called on PUT, and should update an existing product and
>   return them (or rc.ALL_OK.)
>
> **delete** is called on DELETE, and should delete an existing object.
>   Should not return anything, just
>   rc.DELETED.

Just create a instance variable and set it to the request.user object or pass the django user object to your classmethod.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the instance variable neither the classmethod worked for me. But I found a solution on this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580653/how-to-access-the-request-user-in-a-piston-classmethod